# Android HDMI- CEC Check TV Power status

Tags: android, android-tv, hdmi

I have check [Android HDMI CEC](https://source.android.com/devices/tv/HDMI-CEC.html)

Find out HDMI Cable is connected or not using below code:

```
     private boolean isHdmiCableAttach() {

        // The file '/sys/devices/virtual/switch/hdmi/state' holds an int -- if it's 1 then an HDMI device is connected.
        // An alternative file to check is '/sys/class/switch/hdmi/state' which exists instead on certain devices.
        File switchFile = new File("/sys/devices/virtual/switch/hdmi/state");

        if (!switchFile.exists()) {
            switchFile = new File("/sys/class/switch/hdmi/state");
        }
        try {
            Scanner switchFileScanner = new Scanner(switchFile);
            int switchValue = switchFileScanner.nextInt();
            switchFileScanner.close();
            return switchValue > 0;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Now I want to find out TV Power on/off using `HDMI-CEC`

I cannot found any help from site I tried to get help from [LibCEC](http://libcec.pulse-eight.com/Adopters/Index/59) but how to integrate `LibCEC` in app?

Can any one help me to get power status or setup `LibCEC`

Comment: did you find any solution ? to turn on/off tv

Comment: @ParthPitroda sorry didn't find anything

Comment: do you know anything about how to fire command from android tvbox to tv ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Android TV already have this feature wherein it provides developer APIs for third-party TV inputs. As mentioned in [TV App](https://source.android.com/devices/tv/#tv_app),

> Android TV provides developer APIs for third-party TV inputs, enabling installed apps to deliver software channels into the live TV experience. To ensure a compatible Android device implementation, the system TV App has some responsibilities regarding surfacing third-party TV inputs and channels to the user.

[TV integration guidelines](https://source.android.com/devices/tv/#tv_integration_guidelines) are listed below:

> Because each country has broadcast-specific requirements (MHEG, Teletext, HbbTV, and more), manufacturers are expected to supply their own solutions for the broadcast app, for example:
>
> - MHEG: native stack
> - Teletext: native stack
> - HbbTV: webkit modification by Opera browser
>
> In the Android L release, Android TV expects device manufacturers to use systems integrators or the Android solutions for regional TV stacks, pass the surface to TV software stacks, or pass the necessary key code to interact with legacy stacks.
>
> Here’s how the broadcast app and TV App interact:
>
> 1. The TV App is in focus, receiving all keys.
> 2. The TV App passes keys (e.g. Red button) to the TV Input device.
> 3. The TV Input device internally integrates with legacy TV stack.
> 4. On receiving an activation keycode (e.g. Red button), the TV Input device activates broadcast apps.
> 5. A broadcast app takes focus in the TV App and handles user actions.

For a more detailed information, please try going through [TV Input Framework](https://source.android.com/devices/tv/) and you may want to also check the CEC integration on Android TV as shown in the [documentation](https://source.android.com/devices/tv/#hdmi-cec).

Comment: thanks for explan but how can i get this status, Power is on off of TV using HDMI Cable, My app on device using hdmi cable i need to setup app

Comment: Hi Pankaj, how did u get the Tv ON/OFF status using HDMI cec? Thanks in Advance!

Comment: @Kanagalingam sorry i dignt get status.